# Yii 2 starter kit - Couldn't find env file: C:\Users\fanto\....\myproject3.com\.env when starting with `composer run-script docker:start` in docker

Tags: docker, yii2

Yii 2 starter kit - error when starting with `composer run-script docker:start`

```
Couldn't find env file: C:\Users\fanto\ferratum\wapp\myproject3.com\.env
Script docker-compose up --force-recreate -d handling the docker:start event returned with error code 1
```

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project must be launched with a different parameter - with the **build** parameter, 
as initially, the project has not built vendor libraries and prepared environment. There was a mistake in the documentation

(
https://github.com/yii2-starter-kit/yii2-starter-kit/pull/742

https://github.com/yii2-starter-kit/yii2-starter-kit/commit/9415b
)

Change the initial command from

`composer run-script docker:`**`start`**

to

`composer run-script docker:`**`build`**

which also initializes the environment variables